# Show less records initially in UITableView in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

When I hit the server i am getting multiple records, but I want to display only three records for each section in UITableView initially.

Later on user press more button I want to display more records.

Can any one please give any ideas on these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you populating your array? Show that code.

Answer (score 3):

control your `numberOfRowsInSection`.

Return 3 initially when user presses more update the row count to your data(possibly an array) count and reload the section.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this sample . If you just want to display few records at launch time n later on want to load more cells, this might help you ..

https://github.com/Abizern/PartialTable